# Is my .htaccess rule creating an infinite loop?

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Whenever I type a made up address that includes a directory index it removes it. The problem is when the the address includes a forbidden subdirectory. It reduces itself until it hits forbidden. How do I get it to redirect to the homepage instead of reducing itself?

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php

# REDIRECT www to non-wwww
# Set Canonical URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# REMOVE Directory Index From URL
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/)?index\.(htm?|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Custom Error Documents
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404_notfound.htm
```

Comment: I'm just a bit puzzled by your "forbidden subdirectory" statement. Is this _forbidden_ as in 403-Forbidden (unauthorized)? IMO your `RewriteRule` would result in a redirect loop for any legitimate URL as well?

Comment: Yes, it is 403 forbidden. I don't understand why the RewriteRule would result in a redirect loop for any legitimate URL.

Comment: Are you saying then that it does **not** result in a redirect loop for legitmate URLs? It literally is only for 403 URLs? How are you serving/protecting your content - is this later in your server-side code?

Comment: @w3d Sorry for the messed up formatting. That main problem is when it is `rootdomain.com/forbidden403/madeupfakesubdirectory/madeupfake` - it shows a 404 THEN reduces to `rootdomain/madeupfakesubdirectory/index.html`THEN reduces to `rootdomain.com/forbidden403`. Shouldn't it redirect to a 404 page then redirect to the homepage ABSOLUTELY?

Comment: @w3d  No legitimate urls work just fine. For example:`rootdomain.com` - fine. `rootdomain.com/foo` - fine . `rootdomain.com/madeupfakesubdirectory` - 404 then redirects to `rootdomain.com`